# add-apt-respository keeps timing out

Tags: apt, ppa, i3-wm

I'm trying to add a ppa to install i3 gaps on my ubuntu machine, but add-apt-respository keeps timing out every time.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 364, in <module>
    sys.exit(0 if addaptrepo.main() else 1)
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 347, in main
    shortcut = handler(source, **shortcut_params)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/shortcuts.py", line 40, in shortcut_handler
    return handler(shortcut, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 82, in __init__
    if self.lpppa.publish_debug_symbols:
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 120, in lpppa
    self._lpppa = self.lpteam.getPPAByName(name=self.ppaname)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 107, in lpteam
    self._lpteam = self.lp.people(self.teamname)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 98, in lp
    self._lp = login_func("%s.%s" % (self.__module__, self.__class__.__name__),
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/launchpadlib/launchpad.py", line 494, in login_anonymously
    return cls(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/launchpadlib/launchpad.py", line 230, in __init__
    super(Launchpad, self).__init__(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lazr/restfulclient/resource.py", line 472, in __init__
    self._wadl = self._browser.get_wadl_application(self._root_uri)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lazr/restfulclient/_browser.py", line 447, in get_wadl_application
    response, content = self._request(url, media_type=wadl_type)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lazr/restfulclient/_browser.py", line 389, in _request
    response, content = self._request_and_retry(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lazr/restfulclient/_browser.py", line 359, in _request_and_retry
    response, content = self._connection.request(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1725, in request
    (response, content) = self._request(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/launchpadlib/launchpad.py", line 144, in _request
    response, content = super(LaunchpadOAuthAwareHttp, self)._request(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lazr/restfulclient/_browser.py", line 184, in _request
    return super(RestfulHttp, self)._request(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1441, in _request
    (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1363, in _conn_request
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1153, in connect
    sock.connect((self.host, self.port))
TimeoutError: [Errno 110] Connection timed out
```

What do I do to fix this? I've tried a few different repositories with the package I need, but the same thing happens.

Comment: I'm on the latest version of Ubuntu (22.04), and I haven't done anything to python3.

Answer (score 7):

For me, it was a problem with the computer trying to use IPv6 to connect when it was not set up.

Running the following to disable IPv6 and then trying again worked for me.

```
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6=1
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to ping the PPA server using this command:

`ping ppa.launchpadcontent.net`

For reference, this DNS record was [announced in 2022](https://blog.launchpad.net/ppa/new-domain-names-for-ppas).

If your machine is unable to contact the PPA server, the `add-apt-respository` command will appear unresponsive or eventually time out.

This could be caused by firewalls, DNS issues, or any other network problem.